# Failed to load webpack.config.js file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, module, frontend, webpack-module-federation

I am using module federation with react while developing micro frontend website. However, when I containerize the MFE I get the following error. I have tried different strategies but couldn't find any useful content. Has anybody containerized the MFE using module federation? [image]

Comment: have you found a solution?